# Perl: Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<) at /Date/Manip.pm

Tags: perl, date, module, warnings

This has me puzzled. This code worked on another server, but it's failing on Perl v5.8.8 with [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Date-Manip) loaded from CPAN today.

```
Warning:
Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<) at /home/downside/lib/Date/Manip.pm line 3327.
at dailyupdate.pl line 13
        main::__ANON__('Use of uninitialized value in numeric lt (<) at
/home/downsid...') called at
/home/downside/lib/Date/Manip.pm line 3327
        Date::Manip::Date_SecsSince1970GMT(09, 16, 2008, 00, 21, 22) called at
/home/downside/lib/Date/Manip.pm line 1905
        Date::Manip::UnixDate('today', '%Y-%m-%d') called at
TICKER/SYMBOLS/updatesymbols.pm line 122
        TICKER::SYMBOLS::updatesymbols::getdate() called at
TICKER/SYMBOLS/updatesymbols.pm line 439
        TICKER::SYMBOLS::updatesymbols::updatesymbol('DBI::db=HASH(0x87fcc34)',
'TICKER::SYMBOLS::symbol=HASH(0x8a43540)') called at
TICKER/SYMBOLS/updatesymbols.pm line 565
TICKER::SYMBOLS::updatesymbols::updatesymbols('DBI::db=HASH(0x87fcc34)', 1, 0, -1) called at
dailyupdate.pl line 149
        EDGAR::updatesymbols('DBI::db=HASH(0x87fcc34)', 1, 0, -1) called at
dailyupdate.pl line 180
        EDGAR::dailyupdate() called at dailyupdate.pl line 193
```

The code that's failing is simply:

```
sub getdate()
{    my $err;                ## today
    &Date::Manip::Date_Init('TZ=EST5EDT');       
    my $today = Date::Manip::UnixDate('today','%Y-%m-%d'); ## today's date
    ####print "Today is ",$today,"\n";        ## ***TEMP***
    return($today);
}
```

That's right; [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Date-Manip) is failing for `"today"`.

The line in [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Date-Manip) that is failing is:

```
  my($tz)=$Cnf{"ConvTZ"};  
  $tz=$Cnf{"TZ"}  if (! $tz);  
  $tz=$Zone{"n2o"}{lc($tz)}  if ($tz !~ /^[+-]\d{4}$/);  

  my($tzs)=1;  
  $tzs=-1 if ($tz<0); ### ERROR OCCURS HERE
```

So [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Date-Manip) is assuming that `$Cnf` has been initialized with elements `"ConvTZ"` or `"TZ"`.  Those are initialized in `Date_Init`, so that should have been taken care of.

It's only failing in my large program.  If I just extract "`getdate()`" above
and run it standalone, there's no error.  So there's something about the
global environment that affects this.

This seems to be a known, but not understood problem.  If you search Google for
"Use of uninitialized value date manip" there are about 2400 hits.
This error has been reported with [MythTV](http://www.lemis.com/grog/videorecorder/mythsetup-sep-2006.html) and [grepmail](http://www.cpan.org/modules/by-module/Mail/grepmail-4.51.readme).

Comment: it's hard to read your code.  If you make sure you paste the code so that each line begins with a tab or at least 3 spaces, it will be better formatted.

Comment: I believe it needs to be 4 spaces.   ("Five is right out.")

Answer (score 3):

It is a [bug](http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=29655) in Date::Manip version 5.48-5.54 for Win32. I've had difficulty with using standard/daylight variants of a timezones, e.g. 'EST5EDT', 'US/Eastern'. The only timezones that appear to work are those without daylight savings, e.g. 'EST'.

It is possible to turn off timezone conversion processing in the Date::Manip module:

```
Date::Manip::Date_Init("ConvTZ=IGNORE");
```

**This will have undesired side-effects if you treat dates correctly**. I would not use this workaround unless you are confident you will be never be processing dates from different timezones.

Answer (score 2):

It's almost certain that your host doesn't have a definition for the timezone you're specifying, which is what's causing a value to be undefined.

Have you checked to make sure a TZ definition file of the same name actually exists on the host?

Answer (score 0):

Date::Manip is supposed to be self-contained. It has a list of all its time zones in its own source, following "$zonesrfc=".

Answer (score -2):

Can you try single-stepping through the debugger to see what exactly is going wrong? It could easily be %Zone that is wrong - %tz may be set correctly on line 1 or 2, but then the lookup on line 3 fails, ending up with undef.

Edit: %Date::Manip::Cnf and %Date::Manip::Zone are global variables, so you should be able to take a dump of them before and after the call to Date::Manip::Date_Init. If I read the source correctly %Cnf should contain a basic skeleton of configuration options before the call to Date_Init, and %Zone should be empty; after Date_Init, TZ should have your chosen value, and %Zone should be populated by a lookup table of time zones.

I see a reference to .DateManip.cnf in %Cnf, which might be something to look at - is it possible that you have such a file in your home directory, or the current working directory, which is overriding the default settings?